# Sourcing .bash_profile doesn't return

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have an access to a Dreamhost subdomain on which I'm trying to run a Django REST app. The server runs on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. Something went wrong in my virtual environment, so I'm trying to follow [Dreamhost's instructions](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django#Installing_a_custom_Python_version) to install Python again. I get stuck at step 4:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

The command doesn't return, and I have to interrupt it to get back. Here's my .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

export NVM_DIR="/home/julius/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
source .bash_profile
```

and here's my .bash_profile:

```
# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash(1) for login shells.

umask 002
PS1='[\h]$ '
. $HOME/.bashrc
export PATH=$HOME/opt/python-3.5.1/bin:$PATH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `.bash_profile` sources `.bashrc`, and your `.bashrc` sources `.bash_profile`. That cannot end well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite recursion when loading `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` since they both source each other. You should probably remove the call to `. $HOME/.bashrc` to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

It never returns because it can never complete. Your `.bash_profile` sources your `.bashrc`, which in turns sources (`.`s) your `.bash_profile`, which sources your `.bashrc`, which ...

The bash `source` command (or `.`, which is just another name for the same thing) is not like a `require` or `import` statement that only happens once.  It is an runtime command that executes the `source`d file every time it's encountered.